# How to find out if your Japan → Korea ferry is going to be cancelled by a typhoon?

Tags: japan, weather-and-climate, ferries, south-korea

I'm on a ferry (in theory) this Friday afternoon from Fukuoka to Busan.  [Typhoon Halong](http://www.weather.com/news/weather-hurricanes/super-typhoon-halong-japan-20140803) now appears to be heading towards that very stretch of sea.

Is there any advance notice of cancellations of ferries, or will I have to go to Fukuoka and find out? I'm currently in Tokyo so not too keen to turn up and have it cancelled.

The ferry is the JR Kyushu Beetle Ferry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at [JR](http://www.jrbeetle.co.jp/)'s English and Japanese-language web sites, but neither of them appears to have any weather alerts, nor even any *section* for weather information or cancellations. Your best bet for accurate information, then, is probably to call them (092-281-2315).

That said, based on the weather prediction, I expect you're going to be cutting it very close.

The Beetle does claim a [97% service rate](http://www.jrbeetle.co.jp/internet/english/welcome/index.html) and the ability to operate in [waves up to 3.5 meters](http://www.jrbeetle.co.jp/internet/english/welcome/index2.html), so I expect that they will operate right to those limits. I wouldn't expect the final decision to run or cancel your particular ferry to be made until the last minute, taking into account weather conditions at the time.

Comment: Waves up to 3.5m? Good grief that'd make for an interesting ride.

Answer (score 2):

For its limited express and Shinkansen(bullet trains), JR waits to announce official typhoon-related cancellations until the morning of the day that particular train runs.  I expect it will not be different with the Beetle ferry - at best a cancellation may be announced the prior evening.

Weather services in Japan often advise "transportation-related cancellations are likely" the day or night before a typhoon's strong winds come to an area.  If that happens to be the case, your ferry will likely be included in said cancellations depending on the time of day you are going.